# jquery hide the active accordion content

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

Im implementing basic jquery accordion, if the accordion content is open,  both slide up and slide down actions are performed. It should only hide (slide up) the content div. Need someone's help.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("h3").click(function() {
    if ($(".accordion-content").is(":visible")) {
      $(".accordion-content").slideUp(600);
      $("span.plusminus").text("+");
    }
    $(this).next(".accordion-content").slideDown(600);
    $(this).find("span.plusminus").text("-");
  });
});
```

```css
h3 {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
}
.accordion-content {
  display: none;
  height: 50px;
}
.plusminus {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion_container">
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum<span class="plusminus">+</span></h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum<span class="plusminus">+</span></h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Works fine</p>
  </div>
  <h3>Lorem Ipsum<span class="plusminus">+</span></h3>
  <div class="accordion-content">
    <p>Works fine</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/phaneendra/L78szd2b/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do,

```
$("h3").click(function() {
  if ($(".accordion-content").is(":visible")) {
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(600);
    $("span.plusminus").text("+");

  }
  $(this).next(".accordion-content").slideToggle(600);
  $(this).find("span.plusminus").text("-");
});
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5416/)

1. Use `SlideToggle()` for the current cliked element.
2. USe `slideUp()` for all the elements except the current one.

**Fix for Icon**

```
$("h3").click(function() {
  var icon = $(this).find("span.plusminus");
  $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp(600);
  $("span.plusminus").not(icon).text("+");
  $(this).next(".accordion-content").slideToggle(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":visible")) {
      icon.text("-");
    } else {
      icon.text("+");
    }
  });
});
```

[**Edited Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5422/)

Comment: thank you. but, now plus minus is not proper. can you please help me in fixing that.

Comment: @dvln let me check that

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.plusminus').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  if (!$(this).hasClass('open')){
    $(this).addClass('open');
    $(".accordion-content").slideDown(600);
  }else{
    $(this).removeClass('open');
    $(".accordion-content").slideUp(600);
  }
 });
}
```